# Hibernate Annotation for Entity existing in more than 1 catalog

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-annotations

I have a Person entity mapped by Hibernate to a database table in a database catalog "Active".  After a period of time, records in this database table in the "Active" catalog are archived/moved to an exact copy of the table in a database Catalog "History".  I have the need to retrieve from both the Active and History Catalogs.  Is there a better way to model this with Hibernate annotations than making an abstract class that 2 classes extend from.

This is what I have now.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Person  {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Person", catalog="Active")
public class PersonActive extends Person {
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Person", catalog="History")
public class PersonHistory extends Person {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, that would be the right way to do it with annotations (you kinda have two tables so you need two entities). Then run a polymorphic query on the `Person` entity. I find this pretty clean by the way.

PS: Can you add a pointer on how to do this with mapping files, I'm really curious.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  In the past when I've had this business requirement with other projects that I was using Spring JDBC, I would just have one class and one row mapper for both of the tables.

I haven't done it before with hibernate, but here's an example

http://old.nabble.com/Mapping-class-to-multiple-tables-with-entity-name-(hibernate-plugin)-to9547563.html

<hibernate-mapping> 
   <class table="CLASS" name="some.my.Class"> 
(...) 
   </class> 

     <class entity-name="archived" table="ARCHIVED_CLASS" 
name="some.my.Class"> 
(...) 
     </class> 
</hibernate-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a subproject of hibernate named shards. It is designed to work with multiple relational databases. If you want to use it, you may need big changes in your code.

Answer (score 0):

My thought would be to write a query to select both tables from db A and B. then create a query with hibernate and map it to your class.

example:

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(
name="GetAllPerson",
query="select * from A.Person inner join B.Person on A.Person.Id = B.Person.Id"
)
public class Person  {
...
}
```

Not sure if it could work, your question made me also curious about the best way to do it :). I'll test it tonight after work and see if its any good.